# How to set up TLS without a certificate authority on a site for internal use

Tags: tls

I wish to set up SSL/TLS for my site. How can I do this on my own without using a certificate authority.
The site will be accessed only via certain machines so I can easily install the public certificates on their browsers.

Comment: By "implement TLS", do you mean "put TLS into effect", or do you mean "write your own TLS handling"? In most circumstances, only the first of those options is a good idea.

Comment: yes i just want to put it into effect .. using the existing validated algorithms without having to rely on an external CA

Comment: Why bother? Let's Encrypt using DNS validation makes using real certificates for non-publicly accessible internal or firewalled sites a no-brainer. And it saves you the bother of having to install certificates on the clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can arrange for the correct certificates to be reliably recognized by clients, then all you need is to produce your own certificate "by yourself", traditionally as a *self-signed certificate*. Tutorials are easily found for that, e.g. with [Linux tools](https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate) or [Windows IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You might also want to run your own CA (e.g. with [this software](http://www.ejbca.org/)), and install the CA certificate in the client browsers -- this is extra initial complexity, but will make things simpler if you need to change some certificates later on (e.g. if the previously installed certificates expire).

Comment: thanks a ton for this .. this is what I was looking for .. I am midway trying to implement this on my local machine.. And at this point I can't seem to figure out how I can use this for a hosted site. I have a host provider where I have to use the cpanel to make any changes.. and I am not sure if I'll be able to do this .. I guess I'll know better once I try it out ..  I'll get back here once I do that ..

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means a security or TLS/SSL expert, but  I do know a few things:

1. Implementing your own version of security protocols, hashing/encryption algorithms, etc. is generally a bad idea in production code. It's fun to do as a learning project though.
2. It's tempting to use client-side encryption when looking for a TLS or SSL, but this goes against best practices.
3. There are tools that help you make self-signed certificates, but I believe most browsers will show a warning to the user for this, which may scare some, if not most, users away.

I haven't tried it myself, but you may want to check out [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1). I can't guarantee it will work, and it may not support TLS, but if you want a free option, it's really the only non-self-signed one I have seen.

If someone comes along and says I'm wrong about what I wrote here, please listen to them! If not, I hope I could help you out.

Good Luck!

Comment: The OP probably doesn't want to do something insane like write a TLS implementation, just use TLS with a self-signed cert, which isn't insane. Yes, StartSSL certificates work with TLS. I'm not sure if it's possible for a cert _not_ to.

Comment: thanks .. I am not trying to create my own algorithms .. just trying to implement the already existing ones .. i know the browser will show warning but since i can control all the machines that will access the site .. i can simply install the public certificates on them.. :)

Comment: StartCom CA is closed since Jan. 1st, 2018, it doesn't issue any new certificate from StartCom name roots.

Comment: The title and text of the question were misleading. I have updated the title to "How to set up TLS without a certificate authority on a site for internal use"

Comment: @MattNordhoff: it's certainly possible for an X.509/PKIX cert to have Extended Key Usage (EKU) that doesn't include the SSL/TLS values (serverAuth, clientAuth) or AnyEKU; common examples are those for S/MIME email and for code-signing (Windows, MacOS, iOS, Java, android at least) and for PDF-signing. There are many other things that use X.509 that aren't as well known and visible. There are also PKIX certs that are used _with_ TLS that aren't _server_ or client certs, namely those for CAs and OCSP responders.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin: because in 2016 StartCom/StartSSL was sold to WoSign, who were caught cheating and starting around the beginning of 2017 distrusted by nearly everybody. After wriggling for about a year they gave up. There are many Stack Qs on this from the time, just search.